How to create a "Split-Bars" plot in Python with matplotlib?
In the datawrapper.de visualizations service a "Split-Bars" plot is available; and I would like to recreate that visualization plot type (programmatically) in Python using matplotlib (or similar library).
I have a dataset as follows:
A           B           C           D
0.52072     0.08571     0.70141     0.01849
0.46156     0.47112     0.92709     0.24230
0.82056     0.07003     0.14328     0.79489
0.64635     0.72227     0.12274     0.06919
0.83555     0.50729     0.65337     0.62428
0.38232     0.19952     0.24025     0.47434
0.97861     0.53296     0.43911     0.40135
0.93070     0.73063     0.06899     0.00429
0.08514     0.98483     0.80090     0.27527
0.93412     0.05890     0.68416     0.81203
0.78269     0.55302     0.30861     0.19934

I want to produce a plot, such as:

How can I recreate this Split-Bar plot type in matplotlib?

Steps taken to find a solution:

No related questions were found on SO.
No google search returns open source code or library with this plot type to reproduce the plot.
Using a generative AI service did not produce the correct output.
Begin to find a solution, define the problem and specify a solution:

Problem Description: The structure seems to be table format; with each cell filled with a shaded area; to a given filled-percentage. Axis lines are removed. Value-text colors change depending on background color. Value-text positions change depending on % value.
Attempts: I tried ax.add_patch(Rectangle(...)), which seems to be the ideal choice for the outer 'legend' color patches and the inner ax %-filled color-patches.

While posting immediate self-answers is encouraged when you have knowledge that isn't on the site, the question posed for that answer still needs to meet site guidelines. In this case you have not shared any data or any real problem, just "how do I complete this task from start to finish", which is too broad a request for Stack Overflow, other issues notwithstanding. If you just want to enter a prompt and get code spitted out at you, it's probably best to stick with generative AI models.

@TylerH "In this case you have not shared any data or any real problem" - I believe I have now addressed this concern.

@TylerH "If you just want to enter a prompt and get code spitted out at you, it's probably best to stick with generative AI models" - I believe I have addressed this concern, more clearly stating that ChatGPT / GenAI solutions failed to produce this plot.

Thanks for adding some data and more clear information, that effort does satisfy (for me) the info needed to at least assemble an answer that solves your problem.

Library code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

# Add every font at the specified location
font_dir = ['path/to/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/']
for font in font_manager.findSystemFonts(font_dir):
    font_manager.fontManager.addfont(font)    
from matplotlib.font_manager import findfont, FontProperties
font = findfont(FontProperties(family=['Roboto']))
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Roboto'


def plot_split_bar(data, metrics, categories, 
                   colors=[(0.6431, 0.9412, 1.0),
                         (0.0, 0.6392, 0.6902),
                         (0.0, 0.349, 0.3765),
                         (0.2039, 0.749, 0.8118),
                         (0.0, 0.4392, 0.4745),
                         (0.3686, 0.8549, 0.9255),
                         (0.0, 0.5373, 0.5804)], 
                   precision=2, fig_size=None):


    numrows = data.shape[0]
    numcols = data.shape[1]
    data_max = np.max(data)*1.025
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    if fig_size:
        fig.set_size_inches(fig_size)
    # Set labels and ticks
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(categories))-0.14)
    ax.set_xticklabels(categories, fontsize=8, fontname='Roboto', ha='left', va='center', y=1.001, weight='bold')
    ax.xaxis.tick_top()
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none') 
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(metrics))+0.26)
    ax.set_yticklabels(metrics, fontsize=7, fontname='Roboto', x=0.025, ha='right')
    ax.spines[['right', 'top','bottom','left']].set_visible(False)
    
    # Add text annotation
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(len(data[i])):
            perc = data[i][j]/data_max
            ax.add_patch(Rectangle((j-.29, i-.25), perc, 0.95,
                                     facecolor = colors[j],
                                     alpha=1,
                                     fill=True,
                                  ))
            text_pos = (j-0.26)+perc if perc < 0.5 else (j-(0.26)+.1)
            text_col = '#333' if perc < 0.5 else 'white'
            text_col = '#333' if text_col=='white' and np.mean(colors[j])>0.5 else text_col
            text_bold = None if perc < 0.5 else 'bold'
            text_perc = f'{data[i][j]:,.{precision}f}' if f'{data[i][j]:,.1f}'[-2:]!='.0' else f'{data[i][j]:,.0f}'
            ax.text(text_pos, i+.15, text_perc, ha='left', va='center', 
                    fontname='Roboto', color=text_col, fontsize=7, weight=text_bold)
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_ylim(0-0.5, numrows)
    ax.set_xlim(0-0.5, numcols)
    
    for j in range(len(categories)):
        ax.add_patch(Rectangle((j-0.31, len(data)+.4), 0.15, .7,
                                 facecolor = colors[j],
                                 clip_on=False,
                                 alpha=1,
                                 fill=True,
                              ))
    plt.show()


Usage with Global CO2 emissions from fossil-fuel data:
Link to dataset
data = pd.DataFrame(arr[1:],columns=arr[0] ).set_index('year').iloc[::-1]
plot_split_bar(data=data.astype(float).to_numpy(), 
               metrics=data.index.tolist(), 
               categories=data.columns, 
               precision=2,
               fig_size=(5, 3)
              )


Usage with Pseudorandom generated data:
cols = 3
data = pd.DataFrame( np.random.rand(5,cols), columns=[chr(65+i) for i in range(cols)]).iloc[::-1]
plot_split_bar(data=data.to_numpy(), 
               metrics=data.index.tolist(), 
               categories=data.columns, 
               precision=2,
               fig_size=(5, 1)
              )


